# If I generate a constructor on my model do I need to generate a new migration?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I had a model, and there were some properties on it... The migration was generated with...
After some days I realize that I need to generate a constructor on this model. do I need to generate a new migration?

Comment: If your model properties does not changed - you can add constructor without any migrations

Comment: You know, you could have tried this to see what happens...